# Joomla 3 - How to set module params programmatically?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-params

I have a module and params are being saved through the config form. I want to add some additional params programmatically e.g. a token?

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can save the params of the module programmatically by taking the instance of the extension table

1: JTable update

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('extension');
$table->load($moduleId);
$table->bind(array('params' => $modparams));
```

Where $modparams is the params of updated params of the module in JSON format.

But the better way to save a value in params of a module I will suggest you create a form field type and use it in your XML form like

2: Form field type.

```
<field name="token" type="mytoken"/>
```

Then in the field file return a hidden field that would be created in place of the XML entry as:

```
return '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->name.'" value="'.$this->value.'" />';
```

When you create your token set it to value of this field and Joomla will save this value in params.
for help on Form field type : https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type